# How to achieve Spotify App like effect (Image Fading and blur with scroll) in Android?

Tags: android, parallax

i am trying to achieve this image fading and blur effect like in Spotify app on iOS :-

The iOS library for this is :-
https://github.com/matteogobbi/MGSpotyViewController

I am trying to achieve the same. For the parallax effect, i am using this library and after certain modifications, i achieved somewhat like the iOS library :-
https://github.com/Gnod/ParallaxListView

Is there any other way to achieve it ?

(Sorry for the gif image. It's not perfect)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look At ObjectAnimator

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html

You can use the Animator to change the alpha value of the views from 00 to FF which will make them fade in or out.